# Sum up variable while using array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sum

i want to sum up my variables headercount and rowcount, when they are used in the array. So i can be more flexible and don't need to adjust all of them.

```
 ET.SubElement(buisness, header[0]).text = row[0]
 ET.SubElement(doc, header[headercount + 1]).text = row[rowcount + 1]
 ET.SubElement(doc, header[headercount + 2]).text = row[rowcount + 2]
```

I tried to this but it didn't work.

```
ET.SubElement(buisness, header[0]).text = row[0]
ET.SubElement(doc, header[headercount =+ 1]).text = row[rowcount =+ 1]
ET.SubElement(doc, header[headercount =+ 2]).text = row[rowcount =+ 2]
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use iteration instead?

```
ET.SubElement(buisness, header[0]).text = row[0]
for i in range(1, 3):
    ET.SubElement(doc, header[headercount + i]).text = row[rowcount + i]
```

Or do you need something different? If so, please provide more details about your issue.